# monitoring dbus messages by python

Tags: python, dbus

I'm trying to make a python application which reads the messages going through DBus, something giving the same output of the bash **dbus-monitor**. According to what I got from my searching the code should be quite plain and clear, something like:

```
import dbus, gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def msg_cb(bus, msg):
    args = msg.get_args_list()
    print "Notification from '%s'" % args[0]
    print "Summary: %s" % args[3]
    print "Body: %s", args[4]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()

    string = "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify'"
    bus.add_match_string(string)
    bus.add_message_filter(msg_cb)

    mainloop = gobject.MainLoop ()
    mainloop.run ()
```

But launching it I only get the message returned by DBus saying the application is connected, differently from what I get if I execute the bash command:

```
dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify'
```

In this case I can watch all the messages matching the filter condition. 
Does anybody please help me to understand where I fail?
Thanks

Comment: This may not answer your question, but installing qt4-dev-tools and launching qtdbusviewer might be worth checking out. I use it for debugging my dbus code quite a bit. I think it might show dbus messages in its output if you run it on the command line. Cheers.

Comment: Looks that the syntax has pretty much changed within only 2 years. At least on my python 2.7.8, I don't get *any* `print` output any more with that "printf-C-style" syntax, although the way how to get the messages seems correct to me.

Answer (score 10):

`Notify` is a method, not a signal, so you need to add `eavesdrop='true'` as part of the match rule, to receive messages which are not intended for you. If you run dbus-monitor, you will notice the `eavesdrop` key in the rules dbus-monitor sets up.

This is a change in behavior, I believe since dbus-1.5.6 where [bug 39450](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39450) was fixed.